# Exception: cannot run map reduce without the js engine

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to run a map/reduce query on a MongoDB collection and I'm getting the following error:

```
uncaught exception: map reduce failed:{
    "errmsg" : "exception: cannot run map reduce without the js engine",
    "code" : 16149,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

I can't seem to turn anything up on google for it.  I've tried searching for the exception message but no one has written about it would seem.  I suspected it might be a privilege issue to start with, but can't find a related privilege.

I didn't set the instance up, so is there some sort of configuration option that could have disabled the js engine, or perhaps a memory limit or something?

Comment: You have to recompile with the js flag with --usev8

Comment: Thanks.  Apparently the folk that set it up had disabled scripting support as per the security recommendations.

Comment: Hmm I have never seen those recommendations...it is recommended not to use JS from client code but the JS engine is essential for Map Reduce and stuff

Comment: @stewartml did my help you or solved your question?

Comment: @Fede em not really - if Sammaye had posted an answer rather than a comment I would have accepted that 6 weeks earlier.  However, if you edit your answer to say which flag you have to enable rather than just "this flag", I'll accept it as the answer :)

Comment: @stewartml sorry for not being clear enough. MongoDb has its own v8 engine so I though that "to enable this flag" would be understood, my mistake. The flag to enable and disable Mongo v8 engine is usev8 as Sammaye stated. I've updated my answer. Btw, thanks for reply me back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have same issue in our system.

MongoDB has its own JS engine V8 configured by default but in our SIT / UAT environments our DBA has disabled JS Engine V8 to run javascript code since it generates security issues.

After this change our application started generating all these issues regarding to map reduce, but after enabling **usev8** flag back again this issue was solved.

If you want to compile mongo sources you can do:

```
scons --release --usev8
```

Hope to help.